# How to secure database configuration file in project?

Tags: php, mysql, secure-coding

I have created on php file for establishing connection with database server. In this file, i am using `mysql_connect()` function with parameters host, username and password of my database server.

```
public class DatabaseConnect
{
function __construct()
{
    mysql_connect('localhost','username','password') or die('Could not connect to mysql server.');
    mysql_select_db('databasename');
}

}
```

Now in this case, username and password are visible to others.

I found one more way to secure the value i.e. `mysql.default_user` and `mysql.default_password`. In which scenario we have to this way?

Or how could i secure my values from others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to put your database credentials in separate file with proper UNIX permissions set, for example 644, and then include this file on top of your script.

The `configuration.php` file will look like:

```
<?php
define (DB_USER, "mysql_user");
define (DB_PASSWORD, "mysql_password");
define (DB_DATABASE, "database_name");
define (DB_HOST, "localhost");
?>
```

Your original script will look something like this:

```
require ("configuration.php");
public class DatabaseConnect
{
function __construct()
{
    mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die('Could not connect to MySQL server.');
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
}

}
```

Comment: Just used copy and paste on your config file specification (blame me ;-)). Had to add quotes around variable names to make it work.

Comment: `get_defined_constants()` can easily expose them to evil developers.

Answer (score 5):

> Now in this case, username and password are visible to others.

Only to those, that have access to your source code. This should not be a problem. But if you want to separate code and database credentials, make sure that the configuration file is located outside the web root.