# How to secure configuration file containing database username and password

Tags: php, security

**Issue**

In order to connect my PHP code with MySQL database I use PDO way, creating variable, assigning it with new PDO object where arguments contain settings such as server, database, login and password. So in resulting code it could look like this:

```
$DAcess=new PDO("mysql:host=server;dbname=database","login","password");
```

I don't feel comfortable having my login data written directly into the code nor do I find it effective in case of possible changes of those data. It was recommended to me to solve this by storing those data in other text file (preferably .INI file) from which it is going to be retrieved anytime I need, for example, having file:

```
xampp/htdoc/EXERCISE/secret/config.ini
```

The problem is If any user figures out the location and name of this file, they can easily access it and its content by entering URL/HTTP request into their browser:

```
server(localhost)/EXERCISE/secret/config.ini
```

It was adviced to me by the same source the file is supposed to be forbidden from acess by those protocols. So I need to be able to acess the file with my PHP code but disallow any user to acess the directory/file on their own. How to do this?

**Possible Solution**

I have been roaming these pages and other similar forumses yet all results of my research with keywords such as "forbidden" were about users who lost permission unintentionally. I have also been looking for Google solution, yet Tutorials I have found were referencing to file located somewhere else in my XAMPP version and were about lines of settings not included in this file in my XAMPP version - considering I have downloaded XAMPP from official page, I should be having recent version, thus those tutorials were outdated.

It left me with no other choice but experiment on my own. After a while, I have found directory "forbidden" in directory "htdoc", have played with those files and have ended up with something looking like solution to my issue.

Specifically, I copied *.htacess* (obviously nameless text file with but extension) and placed its copy into to-be-forbidden directory. I changed nothing in the file but line referencing to login data storing file. I have created my own text file (nameless with but extension *.ldatastore*) where using copied pattern login:password I have written my own desired login data and made *.htacess* use this file instead of original *htdoc/forbidden/.htpassw*.

Since then, it seems it works. Whenever I try to acces those files with my browser on new session (browser closed and opened again, otherwise it doesn't need autentification again), it does not let me browse the directory nor look into its files (neither those which are responsible for those actions such as *.htacess* or those I created myself such as *config.ini*) unless I provide valid login data same to those in *.ldatastore* text file.

So why am I asking this? I feel uncomfortable doing it this way because of several reasons listed below. In case this is the only easy and possible solution, I can live with that, but in case there is much better way you would recommend, I will gladly read that, which is why I am asking for your suggestions. I was also writing this whole text to explain my case fully, provide enough data and express "I have done some research and understanding of the case before asking" so that this would not be by the rules of this page marked as "off-topic".

**Reasons Why I Would Prefer Alternative Solution**

1. I feel like it is XAMPP framework dependant. That the whole module making this work is part of the framework's code while .htacess just marks the directories that should be forbidden by this module. That means I am afraid If I would release my project on proper paid server hosting with their own PHP executing software, it wouldn't work everywhere and that this is just XAMPP way to do it. Correct me If I am wrong and this is solution used widely on any PHP executioner.
2. I was trying to understand the module's documentation located as text file in the "forbidden" directory yet it seems from the documentation this module was developed mainly to make one safe and forbidden server storing secret data accessible then by various different application on different servers rather than just forbidding secret directory (I would leave this directory to be part of my application which is major difference between my usage and by author assumed usage). Correct me If I am wrong and I misunderstood the usage.
3. Despite the fact I cannot acces the files via browser without login data, my PHP code seems to have no problem acessing the files - I used PHP code to retrieve text from text file that should be forbidden this way and it worked (it echoed the text) with no sign of problems. Well, in the end, I certainly would like to make it work this way yet I expected even PHP code that retrieves the text would need to somehow contain login data to have access. This way it feels like anyone instead of entering the reference into browser would make their own PHP code that would acces those files from my server (which would make this act to increase security useless little bit). Correct me If I am wrong and it is not this easy.
4. I feel paranoid that it is not safe enough solution. Correct me If I am wrong and it is totally safe and preffered solution.

**Too Long, Didn't Read**

Is copying and pasting and customizing .htacess file safe enough to make directory forbidden only acessible by my PHP code to retrieve data from there and is it useable on most platforms?

I have recently found in right bar of similar questions this one ([How to secure database configuration file in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952853/how-to-secure-database-configuration-file-in-project)), yet I am not sure whether it can be used in my case, too, and how to do so.

Comment: just place the file outside the website root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Darkbee stated, the simplest way is to have the file outside your website root. This would be accessible on the server, but not to the public under any circumstances.

The alternative is to set the permissions to 400 on the file.

.htaccess could block access, but not blocking access to the server (which needs access) is just a long way of doing what would be simpler just using permissions.

Comment: Thanks you both, DarkBee and Geoff, I'll try it that way.

Comment: Additional question, If I could: I admit I am not experienced with PHP this way so I had to be looking for the way to do this. I have found two ways, alises and virtual host. Are these the valid safe soltuions?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, the database connection should be safe, the PHP script will be executed on the server and not output any usable data for visitors to the site to see. However, making sure that it can't be exploited is too long a topic to cover here.

Comment: Basically: the data can only be exploited in case PHP server fails so instead of execution of the script it outputs the content with the visible data? That way in case I am developing really small and not so important project I can be satisfied with simply this security?