# How can I save variable data in PHP file?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is a way to save a certain settings of my php(ex. phpMyAdmin credentials) by not opening the code. Simply inserting the credential in a textbox and then saving it. This would really help if I'm going to deploy it and don't need to open the code to change the setting/credentials.

Comment: save credentials in a file like` database.php` as an array and use include `database.php ` to load it at the top

Comment: yes，it can. you just save it in php.file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952941/6229548

Comment: Ok I know this method, what I want is that I don't have open any php file, just input it in the GUI and then save the inputed data to the php file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store it in its own class you can access it in a method that retrieves the config from the property

```
// database.php

<?php

class Database{

   private $config = [
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => my_db
   ];

    public function getConfig(){
        return $this->config;
    }
};
```

Then in your php file that renders a page

```
//index.php

<?php

...
include database.php
$database = new Database();
$config = $database->getConfig();
...
```

A more ideal usage you would actually call `$database->getConnection();`
Which would contain the code to build your PDO or mysqli connection object and return it.